# Control several binary outputs with raspberry pi, CD74HC273 D-type flip flops and 5v relays

Tags: raspberry-pi, design, inverter, flipflop

I am using a system with a raspberry pi and multiple d-type flip flop (CD74HC273), its role is to be able to control several digital outputs with a web app.

I use 8 raspbery GPIO bits as data/input bits on each flip flops, and n GPIO bits to select one flip flop and disable the others (with master reset input), so I can control 8 x n digital outputs.

I worked fine when I tested it with leds, so I tried switching to 5v relays, which is the actual goal (below the link to the kind of relay integrated circuit I am using)
https://www.amazon.fr/XCSOURCE-Bouclier-Optocoupleur-Arduino-TE213/dp/B00ZR3B252/ref=sr_1_6?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=relais+5v&qid=1579683668&sr=8-6

But I realized that those are activated by low state input, which is problematic, because 74HC273 output is low state by default if not activated, so activates relays by default, which I don't want.

I am pretty new at electronics, so I don't really know how to fix this problem.

What would be the best solution ? :

- Can I find "active high" relays ?
- Can I find another type of flip-flop that works in the same way, "copying" the input level to the output on clock pulse, but with a "master set" input, all ouputs to high state by default ?
- Should I use 8-bits inverters on every 74HC output ?
- Any great solution I did not think about ? :)

Here is a "sketch" of the circuit (although I don't know exactly what goes on underneath the hood in the integrated relay circuit, that would be the ""?"" bit, but I guess this is a pretty standard component):
[image]

EDIT: found the schematics for the "??? relay module":[image]

EDIT : 
[link to supplier documentation for the electrical lock](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_1wUUb9AbgDmY40I6eVWiWI_IPkCP_NI/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I wouldn't drive relays directly from a 74HC output. How much current does a relay need to activate? The 74HC only drives up to about 20 mA (4mA). In addition, have you installed a flyback diode to the relay, or do the relay have a built-in diode? To your question, inverting is quite simple: just wire the other end of coil either to the ground or to the +5V. Would be nice if you support us with a circuit of your try!

Comment: Hi Tom, actually what I said what not exactly correct, I am not using a relay by itself but one of those little cards with built in diode / transistor with vcc/ground/signal pins on the low current end. So I don't have direct access to the coil. I'll try to draw a sketch of this in the morning (it is night time in France ). Thank you !

Comment: Original post edited with more details !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be very helpful for the community if you explain us for which application on the secondary side you want to build this circuit. I'm confused about your "relay" (not a simple relay) shown in your link above. The relay itself is a good isolator, so the primary side (arduino) is completely galvanically isolated from your 12V system and there is no need to add an optocoppler to it. The optocoppler is useless. Rather, the optocoupler needs an additional current, space, costs and last but not least, it also ages and may fail. I also found a good replacement of your shown relay similar but with a high-level trigger e.g. here:
https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B07V1X2RSP/ref=psdc_2908498031_t3_B07BVXT1ZK?th=1

But I would build such a circuit by myself.
BTW, I hope you'll place some C (10nF or 100nF) to the 74HC273 IC for stabilization the power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp7O4y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Update:
@Ouhbelle Probably this is the circuit of the relay I have linked? Because this schematics has two important problems. The transistor's Collector and Emitter have to be swapped. And the diode (LED) in the signal line my cause problems in the long run. You know company Eumig? - They put in something like this to do some sort of rectification. After a couple of months, one after the other devices have failed. And ruined their business. Imagine, if the signal (from 74HC) is 0, and the transistor ages and get higher temperatures, there is a little flow from 5v reverse current from C to the B of the transistor and it could start a current flow heating up the transistor. Remedy: Short-circuit (bypass) the LED and change resistor to a higher value of about 1k - 2k2 or you could place an additional resistor from B to GND.

I think for your application, you do not need a relay - why not using the same circuit which I demonstrated - just exchange the relay with your lock and drive the lock from a 12V at the upper side; then it would be better to use  another D1 possibly a 1N4007 etc. ? For higher currents, you could also replace the BC547 with a low-side MOSFET.

Edit: Just a suggestion schematics:
https://easyeda.com/oe1tkt/hc273_lock

The R4 is optional but when powering up, it does hold the IRL3103 MOSFET Gate to GND when there are same statics through the contol curcuit. the diode D1 has to be as closed to the LOCK (connector). Additionally a varistor would secure the MOSFET.
You should also limit the current through the 12V supply, eventually with a fuce.
BTW: Your hand schematics has a little problem with the CLK and MR line (the MR signel is the CLR in my schematics) and with this signal I can reset both or more ICs. With the CLK signal I can choose wich D-FF to set.
Compare your and my schematics ....
[image]

Comment: The goal is to unlock 12V - 0,8A electrical locks on every secondary side. I want to be able to repeat this circuit maybe 50+ times to be able to handle a set of lockers, which lock can be controlled by an app
This is why I went for a "prebuilt relay module" to be able to use it easily and repeat it as much as needed.
I found the supplier schematics and have added it to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help !  Just to make sure I understand your solution, do you recommend not using a relay at all, but connecting directly the lock between a 12V power source and a transistor collector end ? Do you still need a flyback diode if not using a relay ? Does it work the same way with a MOSFET ?Other information, the lock is activated by a pulse (20ms if i recall correctly), and we do not need to maintain current through it.

Comment: Yes semiconductors are more reliable then relays, and also yes the lock b/w 12V power and transistor's collector. When ur lock has a little inductivity, then a flyback diode is needed which suppress the sudden voltage spike seen across the inducivity load when its supply current is suddenly interrupted by the transistor's switching off. The voltage peak would destroy the transistor. When you share a datasheet of the lock, we can calculate a usable transistor and other params for your circuit. BC547 drives only 100mA, power MOSFETs are nice, but you have to take care to drive them correctly.

Comment: I don't really know about the inductivity for the lock, I do have a datasheet for the lock but I am not sure it answers the question, (and it is in french). I added a link in the original post anyway.
The supplier emphasized the fact that this lock is not designed to take current for more than 20ms at a time (this is handled by the software end with clock pulses on 74HC). If needed, what extra information should I ask the supplier ?

Comment: It would be good to know the worst case inrush current for the locks. Anyway, an additional flyback diode is cheap and does not disturb the functionality. Found: Tension d'activation ouverture  : 12 à 24 VDC
Intensité : 0,8A à 12v et 2A à 24V
Temps d’activation 500ms (moins de 1s)
Temps de réponse < 20 ms
Consommation : 24w
The 20ms is only the response time; So we can calculate with 1 A, 12 V and 1 sec. activation.Please allow me 3-4 days for a proposal.

Comment: Thanks a lot again Tom! I have passed on the questions to the supplier, I expect his answer hopefully today or Monday. In the meantime I guess I have some reading to do about general electronics and semi conductors!! :)

Comment: Let me know if there is something from the supplier, I draw a schemetics, see answer.

Comment: I haven't heard yet from the supplier, if I understand correctly, your schematics is designed for the worst case scenario with every security possible to protect key components from power surges ?
I have a few additional questions : - do I need a capacitor for every 74HC if I power them from the same 3,3V source (from raspberry pi or external) ? Is there a risk using this power source for multiple 74HC ? Also, I planned on using a computer power source with 3.3V, 5v power (rasp pi) and 12V (magnet), do you see an issue with this ? anything on cable length / diameter that I should consider ?

Comment: Concerning the CLR / CLK wiring, don't both schematics serve the same purpose ?It's either selecting one 74HC to send clock pulse, and reseting everything, or  selecting one 74HC to activate with MR, and sending a clock pulse to all of them but with only one 74HC not reset ?

Comment: Ad capacitor per 74HC, this is especially for supporting local switching currents which is good against EMC, but one C can surly support both 74HC, 10nF is also ok, You can power it from Raspberry - no problem. The 74HC only draw current when switching. You have to connect a good ground system. I think in this application, it is not so important to keep distances short. You do not deal with NF or HF. I draw the 12V wires from the 12V locks stronger, just take same wire diameter like the locks wire.

Comment: Ad CLR/CLK, for your application view you might be right. But think about it from a logical view, also common control: When starting the system, you need to reset once, then all 74HC devices (there may be several counters and other ICs) are cleared. Also the program is easer, you only have to address 8 bits and clock the selected 74HC, clearing is also done with addressing 8 bits with all logical 0 - again clock that 74HC. You don't even need master reset any more. You can wire the Rasp - Reset to /CLR (as long as this has same logic - I guess Raspery has negative logic reset).

Comment: Did you also thought about a serial to parallel output IC like the 74HC595? You can save some wires (lines) and easily cascade several of these 74HC595. I found that page: https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/74hc595.html

Comment: Hi Tom, I ordered components and it works out fine ! I only have the one lock for now, but it works with 15  simulated outputs (R + LED) to 74HC. For the 16th output, I implemented the design with mosfet and it works great! I can control 17 x 8 outputs if I counted correctly so this should be enough.  Next step, get more locks and test if it is still OK when powering multiple lockers + 7HC + rasp from computer power source with 3,3V, 5V and 12V ouputs! Thanks a lot again, you have been of great help !!!! I will let you know about progress!

Comment: I'm glad it works!

Comment: Hey Tom, sorry to bother you again, I have tried to actually build a 8-lock system, which I could not make work. I think I wired something incorrectly once (like one ground wiring was missing), so maybe I fried something, but I can't figure out what happened exactly. Now when I try it again with the initial 1 mosfet setup, I only get 6V through the lock instead of 12V, even with stable 3.3V in place of the signal output, and with a new mosfet. Any idea what might have happened ?

Comment: Hi @Ouhbelle, that sounds strange. Please measure the voltages (negative probe to GND) just at the R1 (100 Ohm) before and after that resistor, when switching on. If all GND connections are good - you can measure the resistance between all GNDs. You may short-bridge that R1 (100 Ohms) - now 0 Ohm... Be carefull with these MOSFET transistors - those devices are sensible against electro static, especially the Gate input! Any news? Which 12V power supply do you use - does this supply enough energy? I hope you didn't break the 74HC output. Did you add something to the HC74 output, any LED or so?

Comment: I think I figured out my mistake when trying to answer your questions! I use a computer power (ATX500CB) that provides several 5v (raspberries), 3.3V (74HCs) and 12v ("power" circuits) voltages + black GND wires. I thought all black wires from this power source were the same 0V, so I did not connect the ground from my 'control' circuit with the one from the "power circuits". When I did, it worked again, meaning that the lock does open when triggered, but with still only around 7v, so it is still kind of weak (around 2.95V measured at the gate (both sides of R1, current is really low))